# Alternative to readline in Python

Tags: python, readline

#### Which is the best alternative to readline in Python?

I want to read a file-like object line by line. This file-like object contains these methods:

- read(): reads a byte string from the file-like object at the current offset.
- seek(): seeks to an offset within the file-like object.
- get_offset(): retrieves the current offset into the file-like object.
- get_size(): retrieves the size of the file-like object.

I can't read the complete text for file greater than 2GB, so I can't do something like that:

```
   for line in file_object.read():
      dostuff(line)
```

I tested some methods to read line by line: these are fine with very small file, but with big file there are so slow. Anyway these are much slower than File readline().
This is an example that I tried:

```
text = ''
while True:
  char = file_object.read(1)
  if char == '':
    return ''
  text += buffer + char
  if char == '\n':
    pos_newline = text.find('\n')
    current_offset += pos_newline + 1
    buffer = text[pos_newline + 1:]
    line = text[:pos_newline]
    return line
```

I also tried to read 10/50/100 characters at a time.

I can use only Standard Libraries.

EDIT: the "file-like" is not iterable.

Comment: You don't need `.readline()`. Directly iterating through file pointer is suitable in the case for line by line iteration.

Comment: @RockyLi Because it's not a file, it's a "file-like".

Comment: @Austin File pointer? What do you mean with that?

Comment: @S.Martinelli, file pointer here is `file_object`.

Comment: @Austin The file object is not iterable.

Comment: Please refer to last code snippet in the answer posted by @AdamSmith to realise what I'm talking about.

Comment: if you use `.read()` does the resulting variable become iterable?

Comment: @SRTHellKitty It iterates char by char, not line by line.

Answer (score 2):

You can read in chunks with

```
while True:
    chunk = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
    if chunk == '':
        # we've reached the end
        break
    # process chunk
```

But it's quite likely that any file-like object you have can be iterated over directly to get lines.

```
for line in f:
    # I don't have readline, but I work anyway hee hee!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that the file object is not iterable. This is the file object: https://github.com/log2timeline/dfvfs/blob/master/dfvfs/file_io/os_file_io.py